# Limit amount of threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, queue

I have a script in python that triggers several parallel telnet connections to different routers to do something. It's working nicely. The list of routers is passed over to the python within a CSV file.

On the other hand, in order to trigger the parallel telnet connections, I use threads. This is the start of my code:

```
oFile = csv.reader(open(FileCsv,"r"), delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
routers = list(oFile)
[. . .]
for i in range(len(routers)):

    # We generate the config file
    ip = routers[i][0]
    CliLine=write_cliLine(routers[i])

    # running routine
    t = MiThread(i,CliLine,ip)
    # wait random number of seconds between threads (0sec to 5sec)
    time.sleep(random.randint(0,5))
    t.start()
```

Today, the amount of threads is given by the amount of rows inside the CSV file (`for i in range(len(routers))`). I know I can limit the maximum amount of threads by limiting the for-loop (`for i in range(10)`). My question is the following:

- Say I limit the amount of threads to 10 and I have 15 rows in my CSV file, then the first 10 rows will be served for sure. How can I put on hold the other 5 and how can I get these 5 rows to be served later on once any of the first 10 routers -threads- are done?

Thanks in advance!

Lucas

Comment: Sounds like you want either `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` or `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` or a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` for this. It's hard to tell you exactly how to implement it without knowing what `MiThread` is doing, but the basic idea is something like this (using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`):

```
def run_mi_thread(i, CliLine, ip):
    # Do whatever MiThread.run does.


oFile = csv.reader(open(FileCsv,"r"), delimiter=",", quotechar="|")
routers = list(oFile)
[. . .]
p = ThreadPool(5) # 5 threads
for i, router in enumerate(routers):
    # We generate the config file
    ip = router[0]
    CliLine= write_cliLine(router)
    p.apply_async(run_mi_thread, args=(i, CliLine, ip))
p.close()
p.join()
```

Using this, at most five concurrent operations will be running. All your other requests will be queued internally by the `ThreadPool`, and will be popped off the queue one by one as the threads in the pool complete tasks.

Note that I removed the delay between launching the threads. You could add that back if you want, but it would only be guaranteed to work properly for the first N tasks, where N is the number of threads in the pool.

Comment: Hi Dano, thanks for your comment. The class MiThread does nothing special: it just triggers the loggin procedure to the router and runs the routine. Your suggestions sounds nice. I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Dano, I,ve tried your suggestion but something ain't working. Indeed, MiThread is a class and in your code the t.start() is missing. Without it, nothing will work.

Comment: @LucasAimaretto `run_mi_thread` gets executed in a background thread without the need of an explicit `start()` call. The reason I mentioned it would be hard to tell you how to implement it is because you need to convert `MiThread` from a `Thread` object to a normal class, or to a function. Probably the easiest thing would be to instantiate the class inside `run_mi_thread`, and then call `mi_thread.run()`.

Comment: Hi @Dano, got it. I got confused and you're right. I did as you suggested: created a new function `run_mi_thread(.)` and from within it I'm calling my class `MiThread(.)`. Now it's working nicely and I can limit the number of threads as expected. Thank you for your help! Lucas